# STL container as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm trying to pass an STL container as a template parameter. In this case, the vector.

Here is my not-functional code:

```
template<template<class> class TContainer, class TObject>
class Foobar
{
public:

    explicit Foobar( TContainer<TObject*> & container )
    :
    container_( container ){}


private:

    TContainer<TObject*> & container_;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<IUnknown*> v;

    Foobar<std::vector, IUnknown*> bla( v );

    return 0;
}
```

Is this, what I'm trying to do possible at all, because the compiler cannot swallow this?

Comment: my first comment was a joke... but in your code are quite a lot of problems. also passing an type (int) and a specified template class (vector<IUnknown*>) is also a design issue. you could start like [here](http://ideone.com/i00l0t).

Comment: pleas explain why it's not functional and what you expect it to do?

Comment: Adding to Tom's comment, please show at least the first compiler error.  There's a vote to close this, but I think if you show that error and ask about it in particular then the question will be left open.

Comment: You code is self-explanatory, I think we can see what you are trying todo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code, here is a working example:

```
template<template<class, class> class TContainer, class TObject>
class Foobar
{
public:
    explicit Foobar( TContainer<TObject*, std::allocator<TObject*>> & container )
    :
    container_( container ){}

private:
    TContainer<TObject*, std::allocator<TObject*>> & container_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<IUnknown*> v;
    Foobar<std::vector, IUnknown> bla( v );
}
```

The main fault of your codes it that `std::vector` takes two template arguments.
It looks like this `template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector;`. Also, [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18613865/906773) is right about the double pointer issue, `IUnknown**`.
However, you could simplify your code with the following:

```
template<class TContainer>
class Foobar
{
public:
    explicit Foobar( TContainer & container )
    :
    container_( container ){}

private:
    TContainer & container_; // Be careful with reference members
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<IUnknown*> v;
    Foobar<std::vector<IUnknown*>> bla( v ); // C++11 decltype(v) could be used
}
```

Comment: Regarding simplified version, how do you know what type is in the vector? (Suppose you want to use for_each on 'container_' inside Foobar.)

Comment: @moose: `typename TContainer::value_type` would give you the type in the vector. Im not sure why you would need that with for_each though.

Comment: if I use lambda function with for_each, I would need the 'TContainer::value_type' as lambda argument.

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility is to make `TContainer` a variadic template:

```
#include <vector>

struct TObject {};
struct IUnknown {};

template<template<class...> class TContainer, class TObject>
class Foobar
{
public:
    explicit Foobar( TContainer<TObject*> & container ) : container_( container ){}
private:
    TContainer<TObject*> & container_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<IUnknown*> v;
    Foobar<std::vector, IUnknown> bla( v );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: VS2010 cannot compile that. It seems like '<class...>' is the problem.

Comment: @moose Yeah, VS doesn't support variadics yet. Should work in VS 2013 though.

Answer (score 9):

There are three different kinds of template arguments: values, types, and templates:

```
template <int value_argument> class C { };
template <class type_argument> class D { };
template <template<classT> class template_argument> class E { };
```

When you use these templates you have to provide an argument of the correct kind:

```
C<3> c;
D<int> d;
E<C> e;
```

When you use the third form, a template template argument, the template passed as the argument must match the declaration of the template template argument. In my simple examples, the template `E` expects a template template argument that takes one type argument.

In the code in the question, the first argument in the declaration of `Foobar` is `template <class> class TContainer`. At the point where it's used, the template that's passed is `std::vector`:

```
Foobar<std::vector, IUnknown*> bla(v);
```

The problem is that the template template argument says that it should have one argument, but the template that's passed as the actual argument has two or more. Formally, `std::vector` is

```
template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector { ... };
```

In order to use `std::vector> as the first argument to`Foobar`, the definition of`Foobar` needs to be changed so that the first argument takes two type arguments:

```
template <template<class, class> TContainer, class TObject> class Foobar { ... };
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but the main problem in this case is that the first argument to `Foobar` is a template with the wrong number of arguments (2 instead of the expected 1).

Comment: @juanchopanza - gack. You're right. Revising...

Comment: @Pet Becker I came here from google a couple of years later and this explanation is still great! Thank you! Just a question, when you provide a template with a single template template argument `template<template<class> class T>` and use `vector` as an actual argument, whose second type can be default when omitted according to definition, why shouldn't compiler use its default argument and still accept passing a vector? I am confused!

Answer (score 1):

You may create a synonym of your vector type with typedef to simplify coding.

```
typedef vector<MyClass> List;
```

Then use List as a template parameter as an "ordinary" type.

```
template<class T, class K>
class Foobar {...}

Foobar<List> variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you probably get some compiler errors, if so you should have added them to the question as right now we can only guess.

Secondly, I'm *guessing* that it's because of your template parameter:

```
Foobar<std::vector, IUnknown*> bla( v );
//                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Here you tell the compiler that the template parameter is a pointer, but then you have the constructor:

```
Foobar( TContainer<TObject*> & container )
//                 ^^^^^^^^
```

In the constructor you declare `container` to be a `TContainer` with `TObject*` members, but since `TObject` already is a pointer you now have a *pointer-to-pointer*. If `TObject` equals `IUnknown*` then `TObject*` equals `IUnknown**`. You have the same problem when declaring the `container_` member variable.

I recommend you drop the pointer-type when declaring `bla`:

```
Foobar<std::vector, IUnknown> bla( v );
//                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: AFAIK, according to my code above, TObject = IUnknown*.

Comment: @moose Yes, and the you add another asterisk to `TObject` making `TObject*` the same as `IUnknown**`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are wrong.

Comment: @moose Then *edit your question* to include the actual errors! Otherwise we will just be stumbling in the dark and guess wildly.