# Using an instance of an std::array<Type, N> as a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to create some sort of comparison function that will compare certain  prefixes that are known at compile time to other buffers.

I'm trying to use the predefined `std::array`s that hold the prefixes as template parameters.

Here is what I tried:

```
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> ARRAY_A {{0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF}};
constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> ARRAY_B {{0xBA, 0xD, 0xF0, 0x0D}};

enum class Foo{
    A,B

    };

template<size_t SizeOfHeader, std::array<std::uint8_t, SizeOfHeader> Header, Foo f> 
void foo()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<template<class, class> class TContainer, Foo f> 
void foo2()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    foo2<ARRAY_A, Foo::A>();
    foo<ARRAY_A.size(), ARRAY_A, Foo::A>();
    return 0;
}
```

These attempts were made after reading the following answers which seemed related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613770/stl-container-as-a-template-parameter) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108029/how-can-i-use-stdarray-for-a-template-parameter-of-the-form-templatetypena).

I'm interested in understanding the errors in the code as much as finding a working solution :)

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dbb85b736a0cef4) is the failed attempt at coliru. The errors are:

```
main.cpp:31:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo2'
    foo2<ARRAY_A, Foo::A>();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:23:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'TContainer'
void foo2()
     ^
main.cpp:32:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    foo<ARRAY_A.size(), ARRAY_A, Foo::A>();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:17:6: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Header'
void foo()
     ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: @Quentin Included full error and a demo link

Comment: Perfect! ------

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass instances of class types as template non-type parameters.

You can pass references and pointers to class types, but not instances themselves.

There has been some discussion about permitting this in a future standard revision (after [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)).

Your code:

```
template<template<class, class> class TContainer, Foo f> 
void foo2()
```

this takes a template template parameter, not an instance of that.

```
template<class, class>
class bob;
```

the template `bob` (not a class instance of it, or a value instance of a class instance of it) is a valid first template argument for `foo2`.

```
template<size_t SizeOfHeader, std::array<std::uint8_t, SizeOfHeader> Header, Foo f> 
void foo()
```

this is not a valid template declaration.  `std::array<std::uint8_t, SizeOfHeader>` is going to be ill-formed there.  I doubt the compiler is mandated to diagnose this error immediately, because `SizeOfHeader` argument to `array` makes the type of `array` dependent.

Comment: Is there a spec section forbidding that or is it just not permitted? And how would I go about sending a reference to e.g. ARRAY_A ?

Comment: @DlavimerTupin just make the parameter type a reference. Note, however, that you can only bind that parameter to static-lifetime objects with external linkage (i.e. globals and static members).

Comment: @Quentin thanks, it did not work without making the reference `const` which makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

You could pass directly the parameters using a variadic template, i.e.:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Ts) == 0>::type f()
{
}

template<std::uint8_t a, std::uint8_t... rest>
void f()
{
    f<rest...>();
}
```

See [variadic function template without formal parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758620/variadic-function-template-without-formal-parameters) for details about the base case.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is use a `constexpr` function and, if you want to impose that is executed compile time, you can use it to (by example) initialize a `constexpr` value.

Unfortunately, you tagged C++11 so `constexpr` function are less flexibles.

The following is a full C++11 working example with a `constexpr` function that, given a couple of `std::array`'s of the same type and dimension return the number of corresponding equal elements. The value is registered in a `constexpr` `val` variable and, moreover, checked with `static_assert`

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t countEqual (std::array<T, N> const & a1,
                                  std::array<T, N> const & a2,
                                  std::size_t pos = 0U,
                                  std::size_t count = 0U)
 {
   return pos < N ? countEqual(a1, a2, pos+1U,
                               a1[pos] == a2[pos] ? ++count : count)
                  : count;
 }

int main (void)
 {
   constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> ARRAY_A {{0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF}};
   constexpr std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> ARRAY_B {{0xBA, 0xAD, 0xF0, 0x0D}};

   constexpr auto val { countEqual(ARRAY_A, ARRAY_B) };

   static_assert( val == 1U , "!" );
 }
```